# goodnight need to keep a calendar event laravel

Tags: php, laravel, calendar

goodnight need to keep a calendar event laravel and make a calendar but I can not do any other please Amano in this and in advance thank you very much 
this is the code of my calendar

```
    <?php

$month=date("n");
$year=date("Y");
$diaActual=date("j");


$diaSemana=date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year))+7;

$ultimoDiaMes=date("d",(mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,1,$year)-1));

$meses=array(1=>"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio",
"Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

    <title>calendario </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #calendar {
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        #calendar caption {
            text-align:left;
            padding:5px 10px;
            background-color:#003366;
            color:#fff;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        #calendar th {
            background-color:#006699;
            color:#fff;
            width:40px;
        }
        #calendar td {
            text-align:right;
            padding:2px 5px;
            background-color:silver;
        }
        #calendar .hoy {
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>calendario </h1>
<table id="calendar">
    <caption><?php echo $meses[$month]." ".$year?></caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Lun</th><th>Mar</th><th>Mie</th><th>Jue</th>
        <th>Vie</th><th>Sab</th><th>Dom</th>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="silver">
        <?php
        $last_cell=$diaSemana+$ultimoDiaMes;
        // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
        // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
        for($i=1;$i<=42;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$diaSemana)
            {
                // determinamos en que dia empieza
                $day=1;
            }
            if($i<$diaSemana || $i>=$last_cell)
            {
                // celca vacia
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }else{
                // mostramos el dia
                if($day==$diaActual)
                    echo "<td class='hoy'>$day</td>";
                else
                    echo "<td>$day</td>";
                $day++;
            }
            // cuando llega al final de la semana, iniciamos una columna nueva
            if($i%7==0)
            {
                echo "</tr><tr>\n";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the structure I only need to add the event and select dates mvc but everything goes to get here

Comment: Please try to elaborate your problem.

Comment: not as complete and have a schedule but does nothing and I need to keep my events and my first time in laravel Is there a way to keep a calendar enventos in laravel please?